# SPARK : How to create aggregate from RDD[Row] in Scala

Tags: json, scala, apache-spark, dataframe, rdd

How do I create a List/Map inside a RDD/DF so that I can get the aggregate ?

I have a file where each row is a JSON object :

```
{
itemId :1122334,

language: [
        {
            name: [
                "US", "FR"
            ],
            value: [
                "english", "french"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: [
                "IND"
            ],
            value: [
                "hindi"
            ]
        }
    ],

country: [
    {
        US: [
            {
                startTime: 2016-06-06T17: 39: 35.000Z,
                endTime: 2016-07-28T07: 00: 00.000Z
            }
        ],
        CANADA: [
            {
                startTime: 2016-06-06T17: 39: 35.000Z,
                endTime: 2016-07-28T07: 00: 00.000Z
            }
        ],
        DENMARK: [
            {
                startTime: 2016-06-06T17: 39: 35.000Z,
                endTime: 2016-07-28T07: 00: 00.000Z
            }
        ],
        FRANCE: [
            {
                startTime: 2016-08-06T17: 39: 35.000Z,
                endTime: 2016-07-28T07: 00: 00.000Z
            }
        ]
    }
]
}, 

{
itemId :1122334,

language: [
        {
            name: [
                "US", "FR"
            ],
            value: [
                "english", "french"
            ]
        },
        {
            name: [
                "IND"
            ],
            value: [
                "hindi"
            ]
        }
    ],

country: [
    {
        US: [
            {
                startTime: 2016-06-06T17: 39: 35.000Z,
                endTime: 2016-07-28T07: 00: 00.000Z
            }
        ],
        CANADA: [
            {
                startTime: 2016-07-06T17: 39: 35.000Z,
                endTime: 2016-07-28T07: 00: 00.000Z
            }
        ],
        DENMARK: [
            {
                startTime: 2016-06-06T17: 39: 35.000Z,
                endTime: 2016-07-28T07: 00: 00.000Z
            }
        ],
        FRANCE: [
            {
                startTime: 2016-08-06T17: 39: 35.000Z,
                endTime: 2016-07-28T07: 00: 00.000Z
            }
        ]
    }
]
}
```

I have matching POJO which gets me the values from the JSON.

```
import com.mapping.data.model.MappingUtils
import com.mapping.data.model.CountryInfo


val mappingPath = "s3://.../"

val timeStamp = "2016-06-06T17: 39: 35.000Z"
val endTimeStamp = "2016-06-07T17: 39: 35.000Z"


val COUNTRY_US = "US"
val COUNTRY_CANADA = "CANADA"
val COUNTRY_DENMARK = "DENMARK"
val COUNTRY_FRANCE = "FRANCE"


val input = sc.textFile(mappingPath)
```

The input is list of jsons where each line is json which I am mapping to the POJO class CountryInfo using MappingUtils which takes care of JSON parsing and conversion:

```
val MappingsList = input.map(x=> {
                    val countryInfo = MappingUtils.getCountryInfoString(x);
                    (countryInfo.getItemId(), countryInfo)
                 }).collectAsMap

MappingsList: scala.collection.Map[String,com.mapping.data.model.CountryInfo] 


def showCountryInfo(x: Option[CountryInfo]) = x match {
      case Some(s) => s
   }
```

But I need to create a DF/RDD so that I can get the aggregates of country and language for based on itemId.

In the given example, if the country's start time is not lesser than "2016-06-07T17: 39: 35.000Z" then the value will be zero.

Which format will be good to create the final aggregate json :

```
1. List ?

    |-----itemId-------|----country-------------------|-----language---------------------|
    |     1122334      |  [US, CANADA,DENMARK]        |      [english,hindi,french]      | 
    |     1122334      |  [US,DENMARK]                |      [english]                   | 
    |------------------|------------------------------|----------------------------------|

2. Map ?    



|-----itemId-------|----country---------------------------------|-----language---------------------|
  |     1122334      |  (US,2) (CANADA,1) (DENMARK,2) (FRANCE, 0) |(english,2) (hindi,1) (french,1)  | 
                |....                                                                                              |
                |....                                                                                              |    
                |....                                                                                              |
                |------------------|--------------------------------------------|----------------------------------|
```

I would like to create a final json which has the aggregate value like :

```
{
    itemId: "1122334",
    country: {
        "US" : 2,
        "CANADA" : 1,
        "DENMARK" : 2,
        "FRANCE" : 0

    },
    language: {
        "english" : 2,
        "french" : 1,
        "hindi" : 1
    }
    }
```

I tried List :

```
val events = sqlContext.sql( "select itemId  EventList")

    val itemList =  events.map(row => {
        val itemId = row.getAs[String](1);
        val countryInfo  = showTitleInfo(MappingsList.get(itemId));

        val country =  new ListBuffer[String]()
        country +=  if (countryInfo.getCountry().getUS().get(0).getStartTime() < endTimeStamp) COUNTRY_US;
        country +=  if (countryInfo.getCountry().getCANADA().get(0).getStartTime() < endTimeStamp) COUNTRY_CANADA;
        country +=  if (countryInfo.getCountry().getDENMARK().get(0).getStartTime() < endTimeStamp) COUNTRY_DENMARK;
        country +=  if (countryInfo.getCountry().getFRANCE().get(0).getStartTime() < endTimeStamp) COUNTRY_FRANCE;

        val languageList =  new ListBuffer[String]()
        val language = countryInfo.getLanguages().collect.foreach(x => languageList += x.getValue());

        Row(itemId, country.toList, languageList.toList)
          })
```

and Map :

```
    val itemList =  events.map(row => {
    val itemId = row.getAs[String](1);
    val countryInfo  = showTitleInfo(MappingsList.get(itemId));

   val country: Map[String, Int] = Map()
   country +=  if (countryInfo.getCountry().getUS().get(0).getStartTime() < endTimeStamp) ('COUNTRY_US' -> 1) else ('COUNTRY_US' -> 0)
   country +=  if (countryInfo.getCountry().getUS().get(0).getStartTime() < endTimeStamp) ('COUNTRY_CANADA' -> 1) else ('COUNTRY_CANADA' -> 0)
   country +=  if (countryInfo.getCountry().getUS().get(0).getStartTime() < endTimeStamp) ('COUNTRY_DENMARK' -> 1) else ('COUNTRY_DENMARK' -> 0)
   country +=  if (countryInfo.getCountry().getUS().get(0).getStartTime() < endTimeStamp) ('COUNTRY_FRANCE' -> 1) else ('COUNTRY_FRANCE' -> 0)


   val language: Map[String, Int] = Map()
   countryInfo.getLanguages().collect.foreach(x => language += (x.getValue -> 1)) ;

    Row(itemId, country, language)
      })
```

But both are getting frozen in Zeppelin. Is there any better way to get aggregates as json ? Which is better List/Map construct the final aggreagate ?

Answer (score 0):

It would be helpful if you restated your question in terms of Spark DataFrame/Dataset and Row; I understand that you ultimately want to use JSON but the details of the JSON input/output are a separate concern.

The function you are looking for is a [Spark SQL aggregate function](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.functions$) (see the group of them on that page).  The functions **collect_list** and **collect_set** are related, but the function you need is not already implemented.

You can implement what I'll call **count_by_value** by deriving from [org.spark.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedAggregateFunction).  This will require some in-depth knowledge of how Spark SQL works.

Once **count_by_value** is implemented, you can use it like this:

```
df.groupBy("itemId").agg(count_by_value(df("country")), count_by_value(df("language")))
```